# node "Failed commissioning" on MAAS and hang on "[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes." shown on node console

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I use vmware-openstack-autopilot to install MAAS and want to deploy its package.

All nodes could not be switched from commissioning to ready state in the Web UI. They switched instead to "Failed commissioning". The console of these nodes shows they hang on

```
[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

I don't know how to go on and need help.

Commissioning uses Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus".
Deploy uses Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus".

Answer (score 0):

MAAS should be using Ubuntu 14.04 to commission. Can you try to update MAAS and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: There are Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 can be used for deployment but only 16.04 is on the commissioning list. Should I change settings file manually?
My test drive version is vmware-openstack-autopilot-16.03.